# add to queue a template function c++

Tags: c++, templates, sfml

i search on google how to store and to execute functions (template function or not) passing in queue but i didn't find an enough good answer...

this is my code

Window.h

```
struct QueueEventFunction {

    std::vector<std::function<void()>> v;  // stores the functions and arguments
                                           // as zero argument lambdas

    template <typename F,/*template <typename U, typename = std::allocator<U> >*/ typename ...Args>
    void Enqueue(F (*f), Args... args)
    {
        v.push_back([=] { f(args...); });  // add function and arguments
                                           // as zero argument lambdas
                                           // that capture the function and arguments
    }

    void CallAll()
    {
        for (auto f : v)
            f();                              // calls all the functions
    }
};

class Window : public sf::RenderWindow {
public:
    Window(sf::VideoMode window, const std::string& title, sf::Uint32 style = 7U, sf::ContextSettings settings = sf::ContextSettings());
    ~Window();
    template <typename F, /*template <typename ...U > */typename ...Args>
    void addQueue(F (*f), Args...args);
    void execQueue();
    
private:
    QueueEventFunction queue;
}

template <typename F, /*template <typename ...U >*/ typename ...Args>
void Window::addQueue(F (*f), Args...args) {
    queue.Enqueue(f, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

void Window::execQueue() {
    queue.CallAll();
}
```

TestWindow.cpp

```
template<typename T>
void add(T a, T b) {
    return a + b;
}

class foo{
public:
    template<typename T> T add( T a, T b){ return a+ b;}
};

int main() {
        Window window(sf::VideoMode(600, 600), "Test Window",7U,sf::ContextSettings());
        window.addQueue(add<int>,1,2);                  // doesn't work
        foo bar;
        window.addQueue(&foo::add<int>,1,2);    // doesn"t work
        window.addQueue(bar.add<int>(1,2));    // doesn"t work
        return 0;
    }
```

i got a external symbol error.
and if i put a function member class it simply doesn't work. (compilation error)

have you got an idea to correctly make the function addQueue<> with args ?

Comment: _"...but it doesn"t work..."_ does it compile ? does it run but not do what you expect ? does it crash ? Help us out here ...

Comment: This question's shown code fails to meet Stackoverflow's requirements for showing a [mre]. Because of that it's unlikely that anyone here can conclusively answer the question; but only guess at the most. You need to [edit] your question to show a minimal example, no more than one or two pages of code (the "minimal" part), that everyone else can cut/paste ***exactly as shown***, compile, run, and reproduce the described issue (the "reproducible" part, this includes any ancillary information, like any input to the program). See [ask] for more information.\

Comment: no, it doesn"t compile, i'm using VS 2019 and it make an error on addQueue

Comment: And the error message is?

Comment: ok i give an minimal example

Comment: i've edited the minimal example

Comment: the error is : any instance of the function model corresponding to the list of arguments

Comment: Your example is 9 files.  That's not minimal.

Comment: A [mre] should be a single file, perhaps an extra header file would be ok; but it shouldn't take more than 20-30 lines of code to reproduce any compilation error. Please take a look at other good Stackoverflow questions, with useful minimal examples, and make your question look like them.

Comment: is it better now ?

Comment: Your Window constructor takes 4 parameters but you pass many more than that.  If you remove all the parameters from the definition and the call that solves that, but then addQueue is a template that takes a function as it's first type parameter but when you call it you pass in `int` as the first type.  If you leave the template types out when you call it they will be deduced automatically.

Comment: ow yes i forgot to remove some parameters to the minimal example

Comment: What about this: https://onlinegdb.com/b7hs7ZWjZ  If I let the compile deduce the template types for addQueue then it works.  If you must supply template parameters (you shouldn't) then decltype helps get the function's type https://onlinegdb.com/zKWAn4D_f

Comment: yes but i also want use the function addQueue to place into others template function such as :addQueue(button.connect<ToggleButton, void, sf::Vector2f>,(sf::RenderWindow&)window, window.getEvent(), &button, &ToggleButton::setPosition, position);

Comment: @JerryJeremiah yes thanks, but if you make add function as template function, it doesn't work

Comment: I see what you are asking - you don't want to supply template parameters to addQueue - you want to supply them to the function pointer you are passing: https://onlinegdb.com/5QTWgrsYR because you can't pass a template - you have to pass a function (a template with the parameters filled in)

Comment: you're magic. i implement your solution but i have an external symbol problem on VS2019... you say i have to pass a function... ok but how about a class function member ? i tried but i dont see how pass the function (without parameters into) and not the model. when you speak about the model is it something like this : addQueue(&ToggleButton::connect<...>,...) ? because if i pass addQueue(button.connect<...>, ...) i'm getting error - the same if i pass addQueue(button.connect<...>(params))

Comment: A class member function isn't the same thing as a normal pointer.  So change the thing to allow a std::function as well (change the `F (*f)` to `F f`) like this https://onlinegdb.com/AHXbgbhwF  I passed a lambda that captures the class's this pointer but you could also call std::bind

Comment: Actually here is one that calls it with a lambda for a member function, with bind for a member function, with a global function pointer and with a class static member function: https://onlinegdb.com/t9WczrL-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The big problem with your code is that you take the function pointer as a pointer

```
template <typename F, typename ...Args>
void Enqueue(F (*f), Args... args)
```

and

```
template <typename F, typename ...Args>
void addQueue(F (*f), Args...args);
```

What you really want is

```
template <typename F, typename ...Args>
void Enqueue(F f, Args... args)
```

and

```
template <typename F, typename ...Args>
void addQueue(F f, Args...args);
```

And then you can pass any callable thing.  Then you can use it with results of bind, lambdas, class member functions, class static member functions, and normal functions.

Then you can use it like

```
template<typename T>
int add(T a, T b) {
    std::cout << "add(" << a << "," << b << ") -> " << a+b << "\n";
    return a + b;
}

class foo{
public:
    template<typename T>
    T add( T a, T b) {
        std::cout << "foo::add(" << a << "," << b << ") -> " << a+b << "\n";
        return a + b;
    }

    template<typename T>
    static T static_add( T a, T b) {
        std::cout << "foo::static_add(" << a << "," << b << ") -> " << a+b << "\n";
        return a + b;
    }
};

int main() {
    Window window(sf::VideoMode(600, 600),"Test Window",7U,sf::ContextSettings());

    foo bar;
    auto bar_add = [&bar](auto a,auto b){ return bar.add<int>(a,b); };
    auto bind_add = std::bind(&foo::add<int>, &bar, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2);

    window.addQueue(bind_add,5,2);
    window.addQueue(bar_add,5,2);
    window.addQueue(add<int>,5,2);
    window.addQueue(foo::static_add<int>,5,2);

    window.execQueue();
    return 0;
}
```

Try it here https://www.onlinegdb.com/t9WczrL-c

Comment: Thanks for help !
i tried to rise the depth of the functions call like this : https://onlinegdb.com/PyjrIZDQk
here it's work but on VS 2019  i have this error : Error C2664 'void main::<lambda_2>::operator ()(void (__cdecl *)(sf::Vector2f),sf::Vector2f) const': impossible to convert argument 1 of 'const _Ty' into 'void (__cdecl *)(sf::Vector2f)' 
 it didn"t...  i don't give up ;)

Comment: I pasted the code from your link into my VS 2022 and it ran with no problems.  Mine is a newer version but I'm not sure why there should be a difference.  What line number is that error for?

Comment: Ok, here is a site where you can choose from hundreds of different versions of different compilers.  I can't find an MSVC compiler that doesn't work with the code from your link: https://godbolt.org/z/KGY37e7dx

Comment: ok thanks i asked to add SFML lib to explorer compiler. for info, an error occurs when i call setPosition(const sf::Vector2f&) from a ToggleButton class. but when i call a single other function it works... 
auto connect2 = [&button2,&window](void (*f)(const sf::Vector2f&), const sf::Vector2f &p)
    { connect<void, const sf::Vector2f&>(f, p); };

    auto setPos2 = [&button2](sf::Vector2f pos) {  
        button2.setPosition(pos); 
    };
it doesn't seem recognize function pointer as pointer but a const parameter from lambda expression if you have a suggestion, it will be welcome ^^

Comment: here an imp of the error : https://onlinegdb.com/aS89TQHzZ

Comment: The problem is that connect2 expects a function pointer as the first parameter instead of a std::function or something more permissive and setPos2 is a capturing lambda and cannot be converted to a function pointer - no capturing lambda can.  And you can't use std::bind because a std::function can't be converted to a function pointer either.  Are you sure you need functions that explicitly take function pointers as parameters?

Comment: It's okay, i resolved my problem ! here my solution : sf::Vector2f position1(300, 200);
    auto connect1 = [&](void (*f)(ToggleButton&, sf::Vector2f&))
    { button1.connect<void, ToggleButton&, sf::Vector2f&>((sf::RenderWindow&)window, window.getEvent(), f, button1, position1); };
    auto setPos1 = [](ToggleButton& b, sf::Vector2f& position) {
        b.setPosition(position); 
    };
    window.addQueue(connect1, setPos1);